# HTML menu collapsing to select should have role="navigation"?

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, menu, wai-aria

i could'nt find nothing on the subject. So i was wondering...

I built a jQuery plugin which collapse html  menu to a select box.
From:

```
<nav role="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://go.to">page</a><li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

To:

```
<div>
    <select>
        <option value="http://go.to">page</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

As i told before i could'nt find any about this neither on HTML5 or ARIA roles spec but should'nt it become:

```
<nav role="navigation">
    <select>
        <option value="http://go.to">page</option>
    </select>
</nav>
```

instead? Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should go from:

```
  <html id="gui">
    <nav role="navigation" aria-labelledby="admin_label" aria-controls="list_nav" aria-owns="gui">
      <h2 id="admin_label">Navigation</h2>

      <select id="select_nav" role="listbox">
        <option role="option" aria-selected="false" aria-owns="gui" value="about:blank">foo</option>
      </select>

      <ul id="list_nav" role="list">
         <li role="listbox" aria-selected="false" aria-owns="gui" value="about:blank">
           <a href="about:blank">page</a>
         </li>
    </nav>
  </html>
```

to:

```
  <html id="gui">
    <nav role="navigation" aria-labelledby="admin_label" aria-controls="select_nav" aria-owns="gui">

      <h2 id="admin_label">Navigation</h2>

      <select id="select_nav" role="listbox">
        <option role="option" aria-selected="false" aria-owns="gui" value="about:blank">foo</option>
      </select>

      <ul id="list_nav" role="listbox">
         <li role="option" aria-selected="false" aria-owns="gui" value="about:blank">
           <a href="about:blank">page</a>
         </li>
    </nav>
  </html>
```

Use the following binding:

- `aria-owns` on the `nav`, `li`, and `option` elements to bind to `gui`
- `listbox` role on `select` and `ul` containers
- `option` role on `option` and `li` elements
- `aria-controls` on the `nav` element to toggle `list_nav`/`select_nav` binding
- `list_nav` and `select_nav` IDs to reference as IDREF bindings
- CSS styles such as:

  ```
   [role='listbox'] { display: none; }
   nav[aria-controls]:target { display:block }
  ```

Since:

> The navigation items need to be contained in an appropriate widget, such as a **tree, menubar, toolbar, or listbox**
>
> The widget should be labelled by using **aria-label** or **aria-labelledby**
>
> **aria-controls** should be set with a value that refers to the content region that is controlled by the navigator
>
> The states and properties of the navigation item should communicate the following.
>
> - Name of the target page or function
> - Current display status
> - Operational selection status
> - Navigation region

**References**

- [WAI-ARIA 1.0 Authoring Practices](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#Site_Navigator_General)
- [Navigation Role Modeling](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#navigation)

Comment: Thank you very much. I've already released jQuery reSmenu but as soon as possible i will update it according to new information.